# What is the difference between single and double quoted strings?

Tags: vimscript, string-manipulation

What is the difference between single and double quoted strings?

Is there a way to get a variable expanded inside a string, or do they always need to be joined like: `'Hello, ' . s:name . '!'`

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The only difference between single and double quoted string is related to backslash. To *display* special characters like newline, bells, tabs, etc, you need to use double-quotes -> `"\n"`.

Within a single-quoted string, `'\'` is itself => `'\n'` is a two-characters string (a backslash + `n`). Within double quotes, you have to double it -> `"\\"`, which makes them un-practical to define regexes.

Regarding string expansion, you have a few choices:

- `'Hello, ' . s:name . '!'`
- `join(['Hello, ', s:name, '!'], '')` -- which we never use
- `printf('Hello %s!', s:name)`
- `lh#fmt#printf('Hello %1!', s:name)` -- from lh-vim-lib, when we don't want to know about types, and when we don't need to format fields, but when we want to use formats like: `'Hello %1. How are you doing %1 this %2`'.

Comment: Is it possible to include `'` inside a single-quoted string?

Comment: @TomHale. Yes it is. Double it. -> `'foo''bar'`, or use both kind of quotes: `'foo'."'".'bar'`

Answer (score 2):

In the Vim documentation a double quoted string and a single quoted string are both referred to as a `string constant`.

- double-quoted `:help expr-string`
- single-quoted `:help literal-string`

The help lists the difference for single quotes as:

> ```
> This string is taken as it is.  No backslashes are removed or have a special
> meaning.  The only exception is that two quotes stand for one quote.
> ```

Because I'm a Javascript developer I see quite a lot of similarity with the single and double quoted strings there - but obviously string contactenation is done with `.` in Vimscript.

Further information from [Learn Vimscript the Hard Way - Strings](https://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/26.html) that has the default kind of string is a double quoted strings with a special section for [Literal Strings](https://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/26.html#literal-strings)

> Vim also lets you use "literal strings" to avoid excessive use of escape sequences.
>
> ...
>
> We'll revisit literal strings when they become most useful, later in the book (when we dive into regular expressions).