# Highlight whitespace using matchadd

Tags: vimrc, regular-expression, formatting

I'm trying to use `matchadd` to highlight different occurrences of whitespace. However, sometimes it doesn't work for some reason. Here is the code:

```
  highlight GroupA guibg=lightgreen
  highlight GroupB guifg=white                " For default Vim color scheme
  highlight GroupC guibg=red
  highlight GroupD guibg=gray
  highlight GroupE guibg=blue

  call matchadd("GroupA", "\t", 11)           " Highlight tabs
  call matchadd("GroupB", " ", 12)            " Don't highlight single spaces

" Highlight initial spaces
" call matchadd("GroupC", "^ \+", 13)         " Why it doesn't work?
  call matchadd("GroupC", "^    ", 13)        " Current workaround

" Highlight 2 or more consequal spaces
  call matchadd("GroupD", "\S\zs\s\{2,}", 14) " Why it doesn't work?
                                              " I haven't found any workaround

" Highlight trailing spaces
" call matchadd("GroupE", " \+$", 15)         " Why it doesn't work?
  call matchadd("GroupE", "    $", 15)        " Current workaround
```

The regular expressions themselves are seems to be correct. If we try to avoid `matchadd`, everything works. So, here it is, just to show the correct behaviour:

test 1:

```
highlight GroupA guibg=lightgreen
match GroupA /\t/
```

test 2:

```
highlight GroupC guibg=red
highlight GroupD guibg=gray
highlight GroupE guibg=blue

 match GroupC /^ \+/
2match GroupD /\S\zs\s\{2,}/
3match GroupE / \+$/
```

Test file (`>---` is for tab, `.` is for space):

```
>---aaaa>---
....bbbb....

foo.bar..baz
```

Comment: Try replacing the double quotes with single quotes to surround the regexes you pass to `matchadd()`. Or try doubling the backslashes.

Comment: @user938271 Wow! Both suggestions work! Thank you very much. It would be cool to have detailed explanation posted as answer.

Comment: Well, it seems I discovered explanation myself: https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/9706/what-is-the-difference-between-single-and-double-quoted-strings

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Inside double-quoted strings some special characters are automatically replaced (see `:h expr-quote`).
For example, the string `"\t"`, containing the two characters `\` and `t`  is automatically transformed into a string containing a single literal tab character.

As a result, any backslash is automatically removed.
This is undesirable if your string must be passed to Vim's regex engine.
For example, if you want to pass the regex `\s\+` to Vim's regex engine via `matchadd()`, it won't work when using double quotes to surround your string, because `\s\+` will be replaced by `s+`.

The solution is to either use single quotes (see `:h expr-'`) because it will prevent the interpolation, or double the backslashes, so that even after Vim removes a backslash, another one still remains.

Usually it's [recommended](https://google.github.io/styleguide/vimscriptguide.xml?showone=Strings#Strings) to use single quotes, unless you really need the double quotes:

> Prefer single quoted strings
>
> Double quoted strings are semantically different in vimscript, and you
>   probably don't want them (they break regexes).
>
> Use double quoted strings when you need an escape sequence (such as
>   "\n") or if you know it doesn't matter and you need to embed single
>   quotes.

Comment: Never thought Google have styleguide for Vimscript!