# What's the functional difference between the key notations "\<xxx>" and '<xxx>'?

Tags: vimscript, key-bindings

I stumbled recently upon a mapping in the [Vim Tips Wiki](https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Folding) that uses an [expr-quote](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/eval.html#expr-quote):

```
nnoremap <silent> <Space> @=(foldlevel('.')?'za':"\<Space>")<CR>
```

and realized it still worked after using a [literal-string](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/eval.html#literal-string) instead:

```
nnoremap <silent> <Space> @=(foldlevel('.')?'za':'<Space>')<CR>
```

I find examples that use expr-quote over literal-string more often than not. Even the documentation for [feedkeys()](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/eval.html#feedkeys()) mentions

> To include special keys into {string}, use double-quotes and "\..."
>   notation |expr-quote|.

Is there any particular reason to prefer the `"\<xxx>"` notation over `'<xxx>'`?

[What is the difference between single and double quoted strings?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/9706/10164) answers this partially for special characters like `\n`, but my question is specifically about the usage of special *named* keys like `<CR>`, `<C-U>`, etc.

Comment: I had a [similar question](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/vim_dev/aRYJI5WWYFY/oEhvWUPaAwAJ) a couple of years ago. Basically, `map` commands parse/guess the keynames specifically, therefore, they translate literal `<keys>` to the right form and you do not need the special form `"\<key>"`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Good question.  The keycode format with wider general usability is `"\<xxx>"`. In any expression this will be replaced with the underlying numerical representation of the associated key (i.e.  the "key code").

Per [`:h keycodes`](https://vimhelp.org/intro.txt.html#keycodes) the other form, `<xxx>`, is used in the documentation to represent *non-printing* keys and, more relevant here, can be used to substitute the associated key *in mappings*.

The mappings-only restriction of `<xxx>` is arguably the most critical difference between the two forms.

To demonstrate take a look at these two expression commands:

```
exe "echom 'hi\<space>there'"
exe "echom 'hi<space>there'"
```

The first will print `hi there` to the command line. The second will print `hi<space>there`.

On the other hand if we put the same expressions in expression mappings...

```
nnoremap <expr> x ":echom 'hi\<space>there'<cr>"
nnoremap <expr> x ":echom 'hi<space>there'<cr>"
```

...then when invoked both will print `hi there`. (Note the oft-seen-in-mappings `<cr>`, without which the preceding command will appear on the command line...followed by a waiting cursor...instead of being executed immediately. Now we recognize that as being another example of the no-backslash form `<xxx>`.)

As a side note, the `"\<xxx>"` form is used quite a bit in certain Vim function parameters so it may be illuminating to go to [`:h eval`](https://vimhelp.org/eval.txt.html#eval) and search for the string `\<` to see a number of examples of this usage.

Comment: aha, *in mappings* is key here (no pun intended). Appreciate the reference to `:h keycodes`.

Comment: @AntoineCotten Sure. Glad it was useful to you.

Answer (score 7):

**3 kinds of <xxxx>**

```
"\<xxxx>"
'<xxxx>'
<xxxx>
```

Let's see `"\<xxxx>"` first, [:h string](https://vimhelp.org/eval.txt.html#string) says:

```
`\<xxx> Special key named "xxx".  e.g. "\<C-W>" for CTRL-W.`
...
```

It's an expression, it's a string, a literal string for keycode, let's see it's relation ship with literal terminal keycode on my `xterm-256color`:

`echo "\a"` output `a`, it's the same as terminal literal keycode
`echo "\b"` output `b`, it's the same as terminal literal keycode
...
`echo "\<space>"` output  , it's the same as terminal literal keycode
`echo "\<c-a>"` output `^a`, it's the same as terminal literal keycode
`echo "\<c-b>"` output `^b`, it's the same as terminal literal keycode
...
`echo "\<c-right>"` output `<80><fd>V`, it's **not the same** as terminal literal keycode
`echo "\<c-left>"`  output `<80><fd>U`, it's **not the same** as terminal literal keycode
`echo "\<f5>"`  output `<80>k5`, it's **not the same** as terminal literal keycode
`echo "\<f6>"`  output `<80>k6`, it's **not the same** as terminal literal keycode
...

So i believe `"\<xxxx>"` is vim's internal keycode for keys, it's the same as terminal literal keycode if it doesn't starts with `0x80`.

Now let's see `'<xxxx>'`, it's the same as `"<xxxx>"`, it's an expression, it's a string, and that's it, there is nothing special about this string.

Now let's see `<xxxx>`, it's not an expression, it's also not a string, it's nothing by itself, it has to be used with  command like `map`.

**Map and all kinds of <xxxx>**

Definition of `map` without `<expr>` is:

```
Map the key sequence {lhs} to {rhs} for the modes where the map command applies.
```

It's **key sequence**, it works like you are typing it, remember that, it's very important.

[:h keycodes](https://vimhelp.org/intro.txt.html#keycodes) says `<xxxx>` can be used with [:h :map](https://vimhelp.org/map.txt.html#%3Amap) command, e.g.

```
inoremap <down> <esc>
```

Above command map `<down>` to `<esc>` in insert mode, `map` family command is smart, they interpret `<xxxx>` style keycode as vim's internal keycode for special keys. Now turn on [:h 'showcmd'](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#%27showcmd%27) , let's see another example:

```
inoremap '<down>' '<esc>'
```

Type <kbd>'</kbd><kbd>down arrow</kbd><kbd>'</kbd> quickly in insert mode, you should see a single `'`, and you are back to `normal mode`, there should be a `'` in right bottom of of your screen. Let's break it down: after you hit <kbd>'</kbd><kbd>down arrow</kbd><kbd>'</kbd> in insert mode, the map triggered, it's result is `'<esc>'`, remember that map without `<expr>` works like you are typing it, so you type <kbd>'</kbd> <kbd>esc</kbd>, vim return to normal mode, the last <kbd>'</kbd> won't be discarded, it waits for you to enter a mark lonely in the right bottom.

Another purpose of this example is to show you that `map` without `<expr>` knows nothing about `expression`, when it saw `<xxxx>`,  it knows it should be interpreted as special key code, it doesn't care if it's surrounded by `'` or `"`.

**The <c-r>=**

Let's see some wrong examples first, assume you want to map `<c-x>` to `<esc>` in insert mode:

```
inoremap <c-x> <c-r>='<esc>'<cr>
```

It won't work, because `map` without `<expr>` works like you are typing it, nothing good will happen if you type `<esc>` in the middle of a string. Continue:

```
inoremap <c-x> <c-r>="\<esc>"<cr>
```

This won't work too, "<xxxx>" doesn't have chance to do their job, for the same reason as above. In this case you must prevent vim from interpreting `<esc>` as key code:

```
inoremap <c-x> <c-r>="\<lt>esc>"<cr>
```

`<lt>` is special keycode for `<`, so after `map` special keycode interpretation, `"\<lt>esc>"` becomes `"\<esc>"`, which is literal keycode for esc.

**The <expr>**

`"\<lt>esc>"` is super ugly, [:h :map-expression](https://vimhelp.org/map.txt.html#%3Amap-expression) is much easier to work with, you provide an expression to `map <expr>`, it's evaluated result will be used as `{rhs}` for `map`, the result is key sequence, the expression is not:

```
inoremap <expr> <c-x> '<esc>'
```

It's simple and beautiful. Don't miss the quote, both `'<xxxx>'` and `"<xxxx>"` work here. Note that `map` still interpret `<xxxx>` as special keycode, this rule won't change, never change, but only for `<xxxx>` on the command, not for the result of the expression.
Let's use another example to explain that. Sometimes you want to use function as an expression:

```
inoremap <c-x> GetEsc()
function! GetEsc()
  return "<esc>"
endfunction
```

Result of `GetEsc()` is `"<esc>"`, you hope that `map` knows it's a special keycode. it won't work, `map` recognize `<xxxx>` as special keycode only if it's typed in the command directly, not for the expression result. The right form is:

```
inoremap <c-x> GetEsc()
function! GetEsc()
  return "\<esc>"
endfunction
```

Comment: See also my [question on vim-dev](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/vim_dev/aRYJI5WWYFY/oEhvWUPaAwAJ) regarding this and the answer from ZyX

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt That part is still missing from help, i don't thing i have seen it.

Comment: There are a few typos in the answer. For example, the part about `'<down>`, you are mapping `'<down>` to `'<esc>'`.  Also "map <c-f> to <esc>" should be "map <c-x> to <esc>".

Comment: @jdhao Thanks, fixed.