# Ultisnips Sinppets in current scope on blank line

Tags: vimrc, vimscript, plugin-ultisnips, snippets

#### Background

I'm using UltiSnips in conjunction with some autocomplete plugins. I have this line controlling the behavior of enter

```
inoremap <expr> <cr>
            \ !empty(UltiSnips#SnippetsInCurrentScope()) ? 
            \ "\<C-R>=UltiSnips#ExpandSnippet()\<cr>" :
            \ pumvisible() ? "\<c-y>" : "\<cr>"
```

The idea is to check for snippets (and expand if necessary) then check for autocomplete suggestions (and select that if it is available) and if nothing is going on, use enter.

#### The Problem

When I press enter on a blank line I don't get a new line. I figured out that what's happening is `UltiSnips#SnippetsInCurrentScope()` returns a bunch of my snippets when I'm at the beginning of a blank line.

The idea of using `UltiSnips#SnippetsInCurrentScope()` is from the UltiSnips docs (part 6, the FAQ) as a stand in for an "IsExpandable" function.

#### Question

Is there another function that captures the spirit of what I want better? If not what is the best way to achieve what I want (just a case that checks if the lines empty?)?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

`UltiSnips#SnippetsInCurrentScope` return all snippets whose trigger `matches` the current word, I think the `match` here means `=~`, not `==`. You need to check word before cursor and the triggers by yourself:

```
function! s:is_ultisnips_expandable()

  " get word before cursor
  let word = matchstr(getline('.'), printf('\v\w*%%%dc\w', col('.') - 1))
  if(empty(word))
    return 0
  endif

  " test word against triggers
  return !empty(filter(UltiSnips#SnippetsInCurrentScope(), {k,v -> k ==# word}))

endfunction


inoremap <expr> <cr>
            \ <sid>is_ultisnips_expandable() ?
            \ "<C-R>=UltiSnips#ExpandSnippet()<cr>" :
            \ pumvisible() ? "<c-y>" : "<cr>"
```

Note that I change your `\<xxxx>` to `<xxxx>`, one should not use `\<xxxx>` in `map` command, check [here](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/20344/whats-the-functional-difference-between-the-key-notations-xxx-and-xxx) for detail.