# How to return keybinding from a function?

Tags: key-bindings, vimscript, functions

I want the below function to return keybindings but all it returns is a string.

```
nmap <expr> <space>t ManageTerminal()

function ManageTerminal()
  if bufname('terminal') ==# 'terminal'
    if expand('%:t') ==# "terminal" 
      return '<C-\><C-N><C-w>q'
    else
      return ':sb terminal<CR>:resize -6<CR>i'
    endif
  else
    return ':split<CR>:resize -6<CR>:te<CR>:file terminal<CR>i'
  endif
endfunction
```

This works just fine.

```
nmap <expr> <space>t bufname('terminal') ==# 'terminal' ? (expand('%:t') ==# "terminal" ? '<C-\><C-N><C-w>q' : ':sb terminal<CR>:resize -6<CR>i') : ':split<CR>:resize -6<CR>:te<CR>:file terminal<CR>i'
```

But it is messy. So how do I return keybindings from a function?

Comment: What do you mean by "return keybindings"? Is the `<space> t` mapping supposed to run one of the commands that you're returning as strings? Why not just call the function and have the function run the appropriate command?

Comment: If, on the other hand, you're trying to dynamically create a mapping just do the entire thing in the function (`nmap ....etc etc`) . It doesn't seem worthwhile to make it happen in two places. Or, I suppose, you could build a string that contains the whole mapping (`return "nmap ... etc etc"`) and do `:exe ManageTerminal()` or something like that.

Comment: Thank you for your time @BLayer. But I found out that this question has a pretty dumb answer. I assumed single quote and double quotes were the same thing in vimscript. But that turned out to be incorrect. `return '<C-\><C-N><C-w>q'` would just return it as a plain string with no meaning. Whereas what I wanted is `return "\<C-\>\<C-N>\<C-w>q"`. This is what I meant by return keybinding

Comment: Okay. Glad you figured out what you wanted to figure out. However, I'd still recommend you try doing things more directly rather than in such a roundabout way. Cheers.

Comment: Possible duplicate: ["What's the functional difference between the key notations "\<xxx>" and '<xxx>'?"](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/20344/18609)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the OP noted and can be found in [What's the functional difference between the key notations "\<xxx>" and '<xxx>'?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/20344/18609), we need [`:help expr-quote`](https://vimhelp.org/eval.txt.html#expr-quote) here:

```
" note that I prefer nnoremap
nnoremap <expr> <space>t ManageTerminal()

function ManageTerminal()
  if bufname('terminal') ==# 'terminal'
    if expand('%:t') ==# "terminal" 
      return "\<C-\>\<C-N>\<C-w>q"
    else
      return ":sbuffer terminal\<CR>:resize -6\<CR>i"
    endif
  else
    return ":split\<CR>:resize -6\<CR>:terminal\<CR>:file terminal\<CR>i"
  endif
endfunction
```